# log4net relative path to an shared config file

Tags: .net, log4net, app-config

I have a log4net logger set up in my application where I initialize multiple log files:

```
<appender name="AlgorithmData" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="H:/Logs/AlgorithmData.csv" />
  <PreserveLogFileNameExtension  value="true" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <ImmediateFlush value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="AlgorithmTimeData" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="H:/Logs/AlgorithmTimeData.log" />
  <PreserveLogFileNameExtension  value="true" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <ImmediateFlush value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Is there a way to put just the file name and append/concatenate a connection to the appsetting value of filepath so I can change the filepath regardless of the enviroment without having to change the logger?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box configuration option for this, but it can easily be set up with a minimum of code.

I understand that you want to store the path to the log folder in `AppSettings` as shown here below.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="logPath" value="H:\Logs" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In the start-up routine of your application, assign the value of the `logPath AppSetting` to a [`Log4net context property`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html).

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["logPath"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logPath"];
```

Configure the output file path of your `RollingFileAppender` with this context property via `%property{logPath}`.

```
<appender name="AlgorithmTimeData" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{logPath}\AlgorithmTimeData.log" />

    <!-- More settings go here. -->
</appender>
```

This results in the log file being created at `H:\Logs\AlgorithmTimeData.log`.